# How to load mailchimp script dynamically

Tags: javascript

I want to load these scripts dynamically. How can I do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/unique-methods/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.dojoRequire(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us19.list-manage.com","uuid":"c372ca001793d25001055195a","lid":"6397783002","uniqueMethods":true}) })</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a function to dynamically create a script tag and pass the required params and append it to DOM, but just sure to `check if the script is already 
added` to DOM don't add it again. 
simple implementation  ->

```
function loadScript(src, id) {
  let isScript = document.scripts.namedItem(id);
  if (isScript) {
    return Promise.resolve("");
  }
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;
    script.id = id;

    script.onload = resolve;
    script.onerror = reject;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
  });

 return promise;
}
```